# Question regarding research project on indigenous ants during Eastern European winter

Tags: entomology, ant

I am by no means biologist (I'm a programmer), but I want to make an experiment that involve the participation of ants. So please excuse my ignorance on the subject and my potentially uninformed questions.

I need to find some ants, but it's fall/winter here in Eastern Europe, so it seems that I won't be able to find in the wild. So my questions are:

1. If I find a species that is local (meaning that it's used to live through winter - maybe entering some kind of lethargy?) is it just putting them in high temperature enough to get them out of this mode?
2. Probably depends on the species, but if I take just few individual workers without a queen, and provide them with food, is it possible for them to live without a queen? Clearly they won't reproduce so their "colony" will disappear, but are the individuals able to live for a while without a queen?

Comment: If that is enough for you, you can actually buy complete ant farms.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have any specific reason for using a wild species? If not, you would have better using a lab lineage (or any ant farm). Breeding a wild species by yourself might be very tricky.

Taking care of an ant colony might not be as easy as you may expect. Your best chance is to target a species of interest based on past studies and visit a lab that is breeding this specific species.